# Mongoid - select DateTime as Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a mongoid model named `Person` with an `updated_at` DateTime field.
I want to query from `Person` and then `group_by` the dates (not datetimes) of `updated_at`, therefore I want to select from `Person` the `updated_at` as a Date instead of DateTime.

Incase of `ActiveRecord` I would do:

```
Person.select("*, DATE(updated_at) as updated_at_date").where(...)
```

How can I achieve that in mongoid?

Thanks.